# How to ensure scheduled service is always running even when program is down?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

I have implemented `ScheduledExecutorService` in my program it works great. I use it to perform a task every 30 seconds. However, the issue is, if I do a deployment of code on my production environment, my program goes down and my `ScheduledExecutorService` stops collecting data. How can I ensure that this service is always up and running, even if I deploy new code onto my production server?

I was thinking I could extract this code into another jar, but my code is so tightly integrated with the `ScheduledExecutorService` that I feel like another jar isn't necessary. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: does the executor service starts collecting data after the production code push is over? If yes, then what is the harm? Say instead of 30 s gap, once in a while it had a minute gap. Production push will probably be a rare occurrence, once a week or more.

Comment: So basically you just want to reset your application? Or do you want to preserve state between the two application instances, before and after a new deployment? As it stands this question is way to vague for anyone to really be able to help you. What is your app? How do you start your app? What systems do you deploy to?

Comment: If you need a part of your program to keep running even when your program is not running, you definitely need two programs.